# How to draw image along with text on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, text-rendering

I want to make a view that,

- can draw text with a single font
- recognizes hyperlinks and makes them tappable
- can draw a set of icon images along with text
- can copy contents

This is what [LINE app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/line/id443904275?mt=8) is doing when it displays messages in talk rooms.

LINE seems to use an non editable `UITextView` with hyperlink recognition options,
but it can display emoji icons other than ones Apple provides.
Does anyone have any idea to accomplish this?

Comment: They most likely created their own font, adding in their emoji at unicode points.

Comment: They have their emoji images as resource in the app bundle. And I think it is rather unrealistic to add custom fonts especially for languages like Japanese. Is it possible to add characters to existing fonts programmatically?

Comment: Doesn't have to be an entire custom font, just add on some characters in an existing one.  However, if their images are in the bundle then it's most definitely not what they are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So custom font may be a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but fonts are very tricky to do right (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `UIWebView` is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using `UIWebView`, but I have to use it inside `UITableViewCell` and I think that will cause performance problems. Also, as far as LINE concerned, they do not seem to use a web view. URLs are first rendered as normal text and they become hyperlinks short after they are drawn, which is the same behavior as `UITextView`.

Comment: I don't think you have to use it inside a `UITableViewCell` use HTML to create a table-like appearance. (At least that's how I'd do it and I could make it look exactly like the screen shot you linked to in the AppStore). It will save you a huge amount of coding effort.